# Boost recursive_wrapper recursion

Tags: c++, boost

I have `binop` struct that represents a binary operation of 2 expressions of the same type.
I have 2 different types of expressions: `arithmetic_expr` and `logical_expr` defined as a boost::variant.

The goal is to have `binop` have two fields: `rhs` and `lhs` of a concrete type of these expressions. How to achieve this?

This is what I came up with so far:

```
template <typename expr_type, typename tag> struct binop;

struct op_plus  {};
typedef boost::variant<
            int,
            boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<arithmetic_expr, op_plus>>  // <-- fails here 'arithmetic_expr': undeclared identifier
    > arithmetic_expr;


struct op_and {};
typedef boost::variant<
            bool,
            boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<logical_expr, op_and>>
    > logical_expr;


template <typename expr_type, typename tag>
struct binop
{
    explicit binop(const expr_type& l, const expr_type& r) : lhs(l), rhs(r) { }
    expr_type lhs, rhs;
};
```

A use case example would be:

```
(((1 + 2) /* arithmetic_expr */ + 3) /* arithmetic_expr */ AND (4 + 5) /* arithmetic_expr */) /* logical_expr */
```

Comment: We could start by defining arithmetic_expr somewhere. I can't see a definition of it in the code above.

Comment: If I forward declare arithmetic_expr as a struct, the compiler complains that the variant declaration is not compatible with the struct..

Comment: do you want to store bound values in your variant, or just the operations? i.e. is the variant designed to be a complete expression or a domain-specific language program that will take input from somewhere else? Can you post an example of the use case?

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

// identity evaluation
int evaluate(int i) { return i; }

// introduce the concep of binary op
template<class ActualOp> struct binary_op;

using add = binary_op<std::plus<int>>;
using subtract = binary_op<std::minus<int>>;
using times = binary_op<std::multiplies<int>>;

// our variant
using expression = boost::variant
<
int,
boost::recursive_wrapper<add>,
boost::recursive_wrapper<subtract>,
boost::recursive_wrapper<times>
>;

// overload for evaluating the variant
struct compute : boost::static_visitor<int>
{
    template<class T> int operator()(const T& t) const { return evaluate(t); }
};


int evaluate(const expression& e)
{
    return boost::apply_visitor(compute(), e);
};

// evaluate the binary op
template<class ActualOp>
struct binary_op
{
    binary_op(expression l, expression r)
    : _l(std::move(l)), _r(std::move(r))
    {}

    ActualOp _op;
    expression _l, _r;
};
template<class Op>
int evaluate(const binary_op<Op>& o) {
    return o._op(evaluate(o._l), evaluate(o._r));
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;


    expression e = add(6, times(3,subtract(7,2)));

    cout << evaluate(e) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
21
```

Comment: that's all good, but say I have `using bool_expression = boost::variant<bool, boost::recursive_wrapper<and>>`. How do I templatize `binary_op.expression` to `bool_expression` ? That's the question

Comment: You'd need to add another variant type that wraps both bool_expression and int_expression. You'd probably also want conversion functions to convert between them. Basically you're building an EBNF so you need a variant for each compound term therein. Good luck! :)

Comment: Exactly, already tried that, but I want to avoid a wrapper variant of the 2 expressions.. not sure if that's possible

Comment: I don't think it is.

Comment: I don't think EBNF means what you think it means :) But yeah, please think about the grammar first. Build corresponding AST. Uncomplicate!